# Changing PdfPTable width from RPGLE using iText

Tags: java, itext, rpgle

I am trying to modify the width of a table inside a .pdf using using RPGLE. I would like to use the 'setWidthPercentage' method to adjust the table size but I can not get it to work in my RPGLE program.

I have found the Java code to set the width of the table.

```
table.setWidthPercentage(90);
```

The problem I am having is translating that code to RPG.

I am able to create a two column table using:

```
newTable = new_pdfptable(2);
```

I tried defining the 'setWidthPercentage' using:

```
dcl-pr  pTable_setWidthPercentage  ExtProc(*JAVA
                                   :'com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable'
                                   :'setWidthPercentage');
   prWidthPct     int(10)   value;
end-pr;
```

When I try to use it I get the '**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**' message.

Any suggestions on how I can change the size of the table?   It defaults to 80% of the page and I need to increase it sightly.

Thanks,
-Rich

Comment: If this [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.librepdf/openpdf/1.3.6/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html) is accurate, then this method needs a float it seems

Comment: Just to help you solve this kind of problem in the future ... There's a troubleshooter in the RPG Cafe: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/troubleshoot-calls-rpg-java. In the section about the NoSuchMethod error, it recommends using the javap command to see the signature. This page in the ILE RPG Programmer's Guide explains how to interpret the Java signature. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=rpg-incorrectly-specifying-method-parameters-in-prototype.